# JPasswordField validation

Tags: java, swing, jpasswordfield

I followed [this Oracles tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/passwordfield.html) about JPasswordField and I created a simple demo application:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JPasswordFieldDemo {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JPasswordField passwordField = new JPasswordField(20);
    JButton button = new JButton("Login");

    public JPasswordFieldDemo() {
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                char[] input = passwordField.getPassword();
                if (performCheck(input)) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct password");
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect password");
                }
            }
        });
        passwordField.setEchoChar('*');
        panel.add(passwordField);
        panel.add(button);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private boolean performCheck(char[] input) {
        boolean isCorrect = false;
        char[] correctPass = { '1', '2', '3' };

        if (input.length != correctPass.length) {
            isCorrect = false;
        }
        if (Arrays.equals(input, correctPass)) {
            isCorrect = true;
        }
        Arrays.fill(correctPass, '0');

        return isCorrect;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new JPasswordFieldDemo();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now, the part that confuses me is in `performCheck` method. My question is:

Is there a any good reason why should I compare lengths of two char arrays (as they did in their tutorial)?

Or my method can look like this too:

```
private boolean performCheck(char[] input) {
        boolean isCorrect = false;
        char[] correctPass = { '1', '2', '3' };

        if (Arrays.equals(input, correctPass)) {
            isCorrect = true;
        }
        Arrays.fill(correctPass, '0');

        return isCorrect;
    }
```

Regards, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example does not reflect the predicate shown in the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/passwordfield.html), which checks the length *first* and then checks the content *only if* the lengths match. Arrays of unequal length can *never* be equal.

```
if (input.length != correctPassword.length) {
    isCorrect = false;
} else {
    isCorrect = Arrays.equals (input, correctPassword);
}
```

Comment: It's a small optimization that need not wait for [profiling](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2064427/230513) on a busy site.

Comment: Also note that "two array references are considered equal if both are `null`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a any good reason why should I compare lengths of two char arrays (as they did in their tutorial)?

I don't think it is required as `Arrays.equals(..)` also does the same before comparing the chars, if you look at the source code:

```
public static boolean equals(char[] a, char[] a2) {
    if (a==a2)
        return true;
    if (a==null || a2==null)
        return false;

    int length = a.length;
    if (a2.length != length)
        return false;

    for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
        if (a[i] != a2[i])
            return false;

    return true;
}
```